# Apache Taste String Id

Tags: mahout

Is it possible to use an id which isn't an integer using taste?

My model may have preferences for remote products. To differentiate these we use a string identifier which is "locationId:itemId". 
I can't see support for this however.
Is there any other way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though it's going to slow things down. Look at `IDMigrator` and implementations and usages in the framework. This is how you can get some help in translating to/from integer IDs automatically.

There is no support for this in the distributed version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209624/mahout-to-read-a-custom-input-file/9719099#9719099). Basically you can extend [FileDataModel](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/file/FileDataModel.html), overriding [readItemIDFromString(String stringID)](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/file/FileDataModel.html#readItemIDFromString%28java.lang.String%29), and perhaps use an [IDMigrator](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/model/IDMigrator.html) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

userId and itemId can be string, so [this is the CustomFileDataModel](https://github.com/KlwntSingh/CustomFileModelMahout) which will convert your string into integer and will keep the map (String,Id) in memory; after recommendations you can get string from id.